# How many jars should I add to make the application working?

Tags: java, json, restlet

I am working on example from "Restlet in action" book. I do not use any IDE, Maven or something else. Just a pure command line. The problem is shown Resource class:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.restlet.data.Reference;
import org.restlet.ext.jackson.JacksonRepresentation;
import org.restlet.representation.Representation;
import org.restlet.resource.Get;
import org.restlet.resource.Put;
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;

public class MailServerResource extends ServerResource {

    @Get
    public Representation toJson() {
        // Create the mail bean
        Mail mail = new Mail();
        mail.setStatus("received");
        mail.setSubject("Message to self");
        mail.setContent("Doh!");
        mail.setAccountRef(new Reference(getReference(), "..").getTargetRef()
                .toString());

        // Wraps the bean with a Jackson representation
        return new JacksonRepresentation<Mail>(mail);
    }

    @Put
    public void store(Representation rep) throws IOException {
        // Parse the JSON representation to get the mail bean
        JacksonRepresentation<Mail> mailRep = new JacksonRepresentation<Mail>(
                rep, Mail.class);
        Mail mail = mailRep.getObject();

       // Output the JSON element values
        System.out.println("Status: " + mail.getStatus());
        System.out.println("Subject: " + mail.getSubject());
        System.out.println("Content: " + mail.getContent());
        System.out.println("Account URI: " + mail.getAccountRef());
    }
}
```

The application containing this class could be compiled. But I have a Runtime exception indicating the missing library. And each time I add the missing library I get new and new exceptions forcing me to add new and new libraries. It seems to be endless. For example:

1. The result of compiling and running the application for the first time: OK. Runtime error while trying to get the resource from browser:

org.restlet.resource.ResourceException: Internal Server Error (500) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory

2. The result after adding com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jar to compile command and to run command: OK. Runtime error:

the same error coused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/smile/SmileFactory

3. The result after adding com.fasterxml.jackson.smile.jar to compile command and to run command: OK. Runtime error:

the same error coused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper

4. The result after adding com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jar to compile command and to run command: OK. Runtime error:

the same error coused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/XmlMapper

And it looks strange because this library is missing in Restlet framework. So I hope it should not be used in the book example. But I go further anyway and add this library downloaded from the net:

5. The result after adding jackson-dataformat-xml-2.8.5.jar to compile command and to run command: OK. Runtime error:

the same error coused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/yaml/YAMLFactory

I give up and ask you for help...

Comment: Note that you do not need to keep adding the extra dependencies to the compile command - as soon as it compiled successfully your compile time classpath was correct and from then on you only need to add the extra dependencies to the runtime classpath.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for exactly that you have build tools that manage transitive dependencies like Gradle, Ant+Ivy or Maven (in best-to-worst order).

If you want to stick to pure commandline, read the documentation of the libraries you use to see what dependencies they have or whether they provide a distribution package where all dependencies are included, then add all those and you should be fine.

Comment: I personally would reverse that that's my worst to best order. :P But you know what they say about opinions

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono I'd be interested in which way you think Maven could be better than Gradle at all, but this is not the place to discuss it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

According to the import, `org.restlet.jar` and `org.restlet.ext.jackson.jar` are both needed. First for base framework, and second for jackson feature supported.

Maybe you need other jars too, but you can find all of them in the zip file  downloaded from [restlet](https://restlet.com/downloads/current/). Download and decompress it and jars are in `lib` folder.